# How to clear python recursion?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

i'm pretty new to python and have few question about recursion error: "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".
I know that this error is in python to avoid stack overflow.
Now i have made example code what is here:

```
import sys

def print1():
    print("1")
    return print2()

def print2():
    print("2")
    return print3()
------------- 
def print3() - def print7() <- (wrote here like this to save some place)
-------------
def print8():
    print("8")
    return print9()

def print9():
    print("9")

def main():
    sys.setrecursionlimit(11)
    print sys.getrecursionlimit()
    print1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now if have set recursion limit to 11, then the code will run, there would be no errors.
Output:

```
11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

If i set the recursion limit to 10, then there will be a error:

```
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nimetu1.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 41, in main
    print1()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 5, in print1
    return print2()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 9, in print2
    return print3()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 13, in print3
    return print4()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 17, in print4
    return print5()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 21, in print5
    return print6()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 25, in print6
    return print7()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 29, in print7
    return print8()
  File "nimetu1.py", line 33, in print8
    return print9()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

My question is, is there any solution to clear the recursion or some other solution, how to write code similar to this, where one function calls another and there is no need for the last function, where current function was called.
For example i could clear the recursion at print2() and run the code with recursion limit at 10.
I want to write a code where is always function calling another function, so to save RAM i think i need some alternative or other solution.
The code may call same function many times too.. so there may be later 3 different same function blocks running, thats what i want to avoid.

Comment: As you don't explain what a use-case would be, from what your code shows, you certainly are on the wrong path to solve your problem.

Comment: My goal is to make terminal based information holder for myself.
For example there is function called Mainmenu, that have choices to call submenus, for example write 1 to go submenu1 or write 2 to go submenu2 , all thouse menus and submenus will be functions.. and thats like how functions always call other funtions.. on every submenu i would like to add "Back" button, like if you insert 0 then you can go back to last menu or submenu so that back button have to call last menu function...

Comment: you should describe menus as objects, not as functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a loop that calls whatever thunk you returned:

```
def main():
  toDo = print1
  while toDo:
    toDo = toDo()
```

`print1` returns what to call next without calling it:

```
def print1():
  print("1")
  return print2
```

The only thing you need for it to stop is to return `False` instead of next function to call.

The stack will be rewound for each call and never accumulated.